# Read Blood group, Age, Gender etc from HealthKit in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, watchos

I am trying to read Personal Details  (**Blood group, Age, Gender**) of `Healthkit` but unable to request for that.

As per **Apple Doc** [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcharacteristictype):

> HealthKit provides five characteristic types: biological sex, blood
> type, birthdate, Fitzpatrick skin type, and wheelchair use. These
> types are used only when asking for permission to read data from the
> HealthKit store.

But i can't make add `HKCharacteristicType` in authorisation request.

I have run Apple [Sample Project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/creating_a_mobility_health_app) which requests for:

```
HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount.rawValue,
HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning.rawValue,
HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.sixMinuteWalkTestDistance.rawValue
```

But when I add

```
HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.bloodType.rawValue
HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.dateOfBirth.rawValue
```

The permission screen does not asks for DOB and Blood Type. See Image:

[image: here]

**Configuration:** Simulator iOS 15.4 and Xcode 13.3

Anyone knows that if we can access Personal Data of HealthKit or not. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `bloodType` and `dateOfBirth` are of type `HKCharacteristicType`

when you call this, the `compactMap` operation will not include your types

```
    private static var allHealthDataTypes: [HKSampleType] {
        let typeIdentifiers: [String] = [
            HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount.rawValue,
            HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.distanceWalkingRunning.rawValue,
            HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.sixMinuteWalkTestDistance.rawValue,
            HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.bloodType.rawValue,
            HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier.dateOfBirth.rawValue
        ]
        
        return typeIdentifiers.compactMap { getSampleType(for: $0) }
    }
```

check `getSampleType`:

```swift
func getSampleType(for identifier: String) -> HKSampleType? {
    if let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier(rawValue: identifier)) {
        return quantityType
    }
    
    if let categoryType = HKCategoryType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier(rawValue: identifier)) {
        return categoryType
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

your types won't fall into any of these `if let`, so this function will return `nil`. You must change the code so you are able to use `HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier` as well.

**EDIT**: An easy way to do this is changing the `readDataTypes` in `HealthData` class to:

```swift
    static var readDataTypes: [HKObjectType] {
        return allHealthDataTypes + [
            HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .dateOfBirth)!,
            HKObjectType.characteristicType(forIdentifier: .bloodType)!
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only request read authorization for the HKCharacteristicTypes, not share authorization. Update your code to add these 2 data types only to the `readDataTypes` variable. Right now you are requesting both read & share for the characteristic types, which is why they are not appearing on the authorization sheet.

Comment: I have passed `Nil` in `share param` and passed `readType` in `readDataTypes`  Still i am not getting those options in permission screen.